# Using TFS Destroy Command

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Please read:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control

It is pretty much self explanatory.

**But what if you want to keep the file and only delete some history?**

Comment: Please do not use the history tag. Instead, [edit] your question to use one of the tags listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/history/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That silly developer is out of luck. You could destroy the whole file and check back in the latest version, but you'd lose merge history and that can bite you later.

There is no "rewrite history" option in TFVC. Only full destruction or tracked changes.